# Does the target of "Planar Binding" experience an irresistible compulsion?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, mind-control

If the target of Planar Binding fails its Charisma saving throw, it "must follow your instructions to the best of its ability".

**How does the target experience the "must" portion of the effect?**  Do they experience an utterly irresistible compulsion? Or does it seem completely natural to them to behave in the manner dictated by the instructions given to them?

> **Planar Binding**
>
> ... first paragraph snipped ...
>
> A bound creature must follow your instructions to the best of its ability. You might command the creature to accompany you on an adventure, to guard a location, or to deliver a message. The creature obeys the letter of your instructions, but **if the creature is hostile to you, it strives to twist your words to achieve its own objectives**. If the creature carries out your instructions completely before the spell ends, it travels to you to report this fact if you are on the same plane of existence. If you are on a different plane of existence, it returns to the place where you bound it and remains there until the spell ends.
>
> ... third paragraph snipped ...

The bold text above seems to suggest that the spell does NOT make instructions "completely natural", and that the creature is thus aware of when an instruction is at odds with its own preferred behavior. For example, if an evil Dao that prefers to torture their slaves is bound with this spell and instructed to "be kind, considerate, respectful, and loving to everyone you interact with", that they are aware of their preferences and the instruction (and the dichotomy between them).

But this leaves unanswered what exactly their experience of the magical effect is, whereby they *must* follow the instructions.  Do they try to act normally but find themselves unconsciously acting in accordance with the instructions (like Jim Carrey in "Liar, Liar")?  Or is their experience more akin to an ongoing internal struggle that they never win, in which they try desperately, every single time, to do what they want to, but are (somehow) **forced** to act in accordance with the instructions?

One fact that may play a role in this is that the Planar Binding spell is an abjuration.  This is somewhat problematic given that the primary effect of the spell is coercive rather than protective (enchantment would make more sense).  However, having it be abjuration makes it more powerful, since numerous entities are immune to enchantment but few are immune to abjuration. Regardless, I'm left unclear **how** the spell enforces the instructions and what the target's subjective experience is.  Knowing the answer to this question will help answer a whole flock of related questions.

Note that there is not a great deal of RAW related to this (that I am aware of), so the standard answer is "it is up to the DM". What I'm looking for is guidance around what is sensible in that context (preferably that aligns with game balance, related game mechanics, etc.)

Comment: Could you please describe a specific problem when it matters?

Comment: @enkryptor: the internal experience of the target effects the ethics of casting this spell.  In my worlds, alignment is not as black-and-white as it is the normal D&D literature, but even so, there is a big difference between a) casting the spell on a creature that, due to magic, willingly abides by instructions and b) casting a spell on a creature that continually feels psychological torture.  Even binding an evil creature and instructing it to "be good" becomes an evil act if it causes the creature inescapable perpetual psychological agony for doing things against its own ethos.

Comment: @enkryptor: As well, I think having an internally-consistent theory of this kind of compulsive magic will go a long way to helping guide (internally consistent) answers to many many related questions.

Comment: There is no real Planar Binding spell we could analyze. It is a fictional thing. Yes we can analyze the spell description from the rules, but how spells actually work in your games is a different story. It's up to your DM more often than not. 5th edition empowers the DM in ways that 3rd, 3.5, and 4th did not. While rule zero has always applied, 5th edition chooses not to explicitly codify many things. It's just how the game works.

Comment: Alignment has no mechanical meaning in 5e anymore, so all ethical questions are now out of the game rules scope. You just can't discuss ethics in context of game mechanics or game balance. How do you (or your DM) roleplay this is completely up to you (and your DM). I vote to close this question as opinion-based.

Comment: An excellent question, but not the sort this site strives to answer. I think @MetaDnd quoted the relevant rules, and the answer to this question isn't there, so any further discussion will need to be based on speculation, ethics and opinion- great seeds for debate, but more appropriate on a forum site than here. I'll vote to close, but hope to follow this conversation in a different setting.

Answer (score 2):

### The rules do not describe internal reasons

The spell description says that the bound creature serves the caster. The reasons why it does that are completely internal, hence, invisible for an external observer.

D&D is not a game about demon feelings, so the mechanics do not say what the creature is supposed to feel. That doesn't mean demons have no feelings, we just have no game rules for that. Instead, the game says what the creature is supposed to *do*.

You can roleplay this as you please, since 5e rules impose little to no restrictions on roleplaying.

One thing is sure, the [*planar binding*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/planar-binding) spell portrays the classic ["binding a demon" fantasy trope](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MagicallyBindingContract). Rather than being enforced by threat of punishment by a lawful governing body, this contract is simply physically impossible to break thanks to some magic. The bound creature is fully aware of the forceful nature of the contract though, we can assume this from the spell description:

> if the creature is hostile to you, it strives to twist your words to achieve its own objectives

So presumably the bound creature is not "unconsciously acting in accordance with the instructions", it follows the instructions due to a magical contract which is impossible to break.

Comment: Every DM is the master of their own dominion, and I have no problem with DMs treating NPCs and PCs differently (and allowing NPCs to do things PCs cannot).  But in my own games, I prefer to have everyone play by the same rules.   As such, in my worlds, the statement "a PC is not supposed to be the subject of the spell, only the caster" makes no sense, since for me  PC == NPC (NPCs are just PCs that I as DM happen to be playing).  This forces me to be consistent in applying rules the same way for everyone. Again, others are of course free to rule otherwise.

Comment: @MetaDnd so what do you do when the game has no rules for a particular situation?

Comment: I think one good possibility for a "theory of binding magic" is the one you mention ... the contract is simply physically impossible to break thanks to some magic.  But we would need to nail down the problematic phrase "to the best of its ability".  More on this issue in upcoming questions...

Comment: I try to identify how that situation is part of a larger picture, then develop an explanation for how (and by whom) that larger picture is implemented in the D&D multiverse. If I'm successful, that theory allows me to answer lots of related questions.  All of the questions I'm posing about Planar Binding are my attempt to find, with the help of the D&D community, an internally consist "theory of binding magic".

Comment: This implies that the "theory of binding magic" exists. What makes you think that?

Comment: I'm the DM.  In my universe, a theory of binding magic exists ;-). I'm looking for crowd sources wisdom on ideas for what that theory is.

Comment: @MetaDnd this effectively turns the question into an idea-generation one. Such kind of questions doesn't work very good at SE. You will probably get better results from a forum. Please check https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/

Comment: @MetaDnd This is worth a separate question entirely, but this mentality that NPCs should follow the same rules that PCs do is explicitly not how D&D works in 5th edition. There’s some overlap, but PCs and NPCs are intentionally bound by different rules.

Answer (score 1):

### Up to the GM.

It's up to the GM how npcs are portrayed, and why and how magic works.  DnD 5e has almost no guidelines as to 'how' things work, unlike some earlier editions that offered at least advice or suggestions.  What advice there is sometimes contradicts itself or is found in like random tweets by people who wrote the book.  In general it's superior for the GM to either make something up themselves or look up generic fantasy tropes/GMing advice for how to handle or describe such things.

**The Default**:  The basic assumption with any such 'contract' or 'binding' in settings with magic (or some kinds of technology) is that magic is being used to enforce that contract or binding by forbidding certain actions.  How exactly the magic knows what to 'forbid' and whether that can be gamed - such as by brainwashing a demon to think 'nice' means 'eating someone's guts', or twisting the meaning of words so you 'defeat' the enemy in a game of chess rather than killing them - is somewhat more variable but can generally be played by ear.

**Other Variants**:  There are multiple other kinds of binding magical enforcement of XYZ that exist in fantasy tropes and the like - they can change the bound entity's personality so it WANTS to do the thing, they can be enforced by a (powerful) authority that everyone is aware of and so toes the line (unless they get really angry or think they can sneakily disobey it), there can be a specific reward for completing the contract that the entity will automatically lose if it disobeys (or a punishment that happens if it disobeys, like pain), and a variety of other, more or less baroque systems.  The advantage of these systems over the default is that when portrayed well, the complex details of why and how this contract works and methods of exploiting that can be very interesting story elements that add value to a game (or book, or movie).  The downside is that it adds complexity, and handled poorly can lead to plot holes.

In general the main rule of any kind of 'how' or 'why' is 'be consistent'.  If you think up an explanation for something, that explanation must make sense with your world and also be persistent - two related things having different explanations needs a reason why, and if something works one way one time and another way another time that also needs a why, and a good why, or it will seem arbitrary and cause people to doubt the underlying logic of your story and/or world.

Comment: Thanks @user2754.  I agree that it is up to the DM (hence my last paragraph).  And I definitely agree that internal consistency is important when creating rulings on such questions.  In fact, this question (and most every other question will be posing) is an exploration of exactly that.  Having a "theory of binding magic" (or many different theories) and exploring as a community the ramifications of the various theories can let us weed out the problematic ones and keep those that honor game balance and internal consistency, and allow us to adjudicate a large collection of related questions.

Comment: See https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/169856/how-does-the-target-of-planar-binding-subjectively-experience-the-effects-of-t for a small list of similar questions (a good theory of binding magic would provide answers for all of them).  I'll be posting each of them as separate questions over the next few days. I welcome input on them and this "theory of binding magic".